# Labels parallel near curves

Tags: pgfplots

I have plotted some curves for different orders of a polynomial. The code and the resulting image look similar to this:

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{semilogxaxis}[
    width= 0.8\textwidth,
    height= 0.5\textwidth,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=40,
    xmin=0.1,
    xmax=10,        
    xlabel=frequency,
    ylabel=damping,
    grid=both,
    major grid style={black!50}
    ]
 \newcommand{\const}{0.25}
 \addplot [domain=0.01:10, samples=1000,smooth]{10*ln(1+\const*(x+1)^(2))/ln(10)};
 \addplot [domain=0.01:10, samples=1000,smooth]{10*ln(1+\const*(2*(x+1)^(2)-1)^2)/ln(10)};
 \addplot [domain=0.01:10, samples=1000,smooth]{10*ln(1+\const*(4*(x+1)^(3)-3*(x+1))^2)/ln(10)};
 \addplot [domain=0.01:10, samples=1000,smooth]{10*ln(1+\const*(8*(x+1)^(4)-8*(x+1)^2+1)^2)/ln(10)}; 
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the code above]

Is there some elegant way to put labels near the curves? I imagine something like using the slopes of the different curves, and accordingly rotating the text of a node, but I don't really know how to do it. Additionaly, the labels should have white background color, but that part should be easy...

A possible outcome may be some labels like these:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can place labels parallel to the plot lines by adding `node [pos=0.6, sloped, anchor=south] {<Text>};` at the end of the `\addplot` lines:

[image]

Note that I reduced the number of samples from 1000 to 30. For a function that's as smooth as this one, you don't need that many sample points.

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{semilogxaxis}[
    width= 0.8\textwidth,
    height= 0.5\textwidth,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=40,
    xmin=0.1,
    xmax=10,        
    xlabel=frequency,
    ylabel=damping,
    grid=both,
    major grid style={black!50},
    /tikz/plot label/.style={
        fill=white,
        sloped,
        anchor=south,
        inner sep=1pt,
        font=\bfseries
    },
    samples=30,
    domain=0.01:10
    ]
 \newcommand{\const}{0.25}
 \addplot [thick, smooth]{10*ln(1+\const*(x+1)^(2))/ln(10)} node [pos=0.65, plot label] {a};
 \addplot [thick, smooth]{10*ln(1+\const*(2*(x+1)^(2)-1)^2)/ln(10)} node [pos=0.55, plot label] {b};
 \addplot [thick, smooth]{10*ln(1+\const*(4*(x+1)^(3)-3*(x+1))^2)/ln(10)} node [pos=0.45, plot label] {c};
 \addplot [thick, smooth]{10*ln(1+\const*(8*(x+1)^(4)-8*(x+1)^2+1)^2)/ln(10)} node [pos=0.38, plot label] {d};
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I somehow must have missed it in the manual... And the `fill=white` looks much better than anything I'd have done :)

Comment: I put some formulas in the node text, and now the white box sometimes inersects a bit with the curves. Some little shift of the labels would solve this... http://i.stack.imgur.com/ofjHd.png

Comment: You can set `outer sep=1pt` to get some separation